# fckeditor -> changes to &gt;

Tags: fckeditor, cmsmadesimple

i have cms made simple usng fckeditor as the wysiwyg editor for content.  i have put this code on my page:

```
{if $ccuser->loggedin()}

Welcome To The Promo Section

{else} Please Login Here{/if}
```

but its changing it to this

```
<p>{if $ccuser-&gt;loggedin()}</p>
<p>Welcome To The Promo Section</p>
<p>{else} Please Login <a href="#">Here</a>{/if}</p>
```

which is causing errors.  How can i get around this so leavs the if statment alone for "->"

Comment: sorry the second refference came through properly... the problem is -> is becoming & gt;  ... i put a space between & and gt; because of the issue with the original posting

Comment: @user520300: Use the **`{}`** button for textual code sample